# Remove the literal "false" boolean value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

```
 public List<LawOfficeDetailEntity> getLawOfficeByManagementUnitId(Long managementUnitId, Boolean statusless) {
        List<LawOfficeDetailEntity> entities = lawOfficeDetailRepository.findByManagementUnitType(String.valueOf(managementUnitId));
        return (statusless == null || statusless == false) ? entities.stream().filter(office -> office.getValidityStatus() == 1).collect(Collectors.toList()) : entities;
    }
```

I have "remove the literal "false" boolean value" sonar error on statusless == false. How can i fix it?

Comment: replace `statusless == false` with `!statusless`

Comment: Have you read how Sonar explains the problem? https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1125

Comment: Doesn't sonarqube also give an explanation (with examples) of the issues it finds?

Answer (score 0):

As you use `Boolean` and not the primitive type `boolean`, you should not compare it with `==`. What you can do is: `statusless == null || !statusless.booleanValue()`

Comment: Even `!Boolean.TRUE.equals(statusless)` should work.

Comment: "you should not compare it with ==" this is only the case if you're comparing it to _another_ non-primitive. Since it's being compared to `false`, `statusless` is unboxed, and `==` is correct.

Comment: @AndyTurner from a wider perspective, having a three-state 'boolean' is definitely not correct. Reducing the question to just 'make sonar shut up', your advice boils down to 'just close your eyes and ignore the warning'? That's.. not what OP asked for. The sonar warning is NOT about the risk of comparing boxed values with `==` - it's simply about redundant `x == true` / `x == false` in boolean compares; sonar wants you to write `x` / `!x` instead. Thus, in both senses of the question, `==` here is certainly not correct.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I am commenting on this answer, not on the question.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes it would work, but the compiler would have to unbox it. It's not a big deal, but I think SonarQube will highlight it as a code smell for needlessly unboxing a Boolean. So for fixing a code smell, you would get another one.

Comment: @retoen `statusless.booleanValue()` is explicitly unboxing it. This is exactly what the compiler translates it to with autounboxing. Unnecessary explicit unboxing is the code smell.

Answer (score -1):

Given that this question is about a linting tool, it is therefore strictly about proper code style and hygiene, and therefore the question is a bit of a tricky one: Yes, there is a way to 'avoid the sonar warning', but that is like handing a bazooka to a child: The one and only reason to use sonar is to write proper code, and the fastest, simplest way to 'avoid the sonar warning' **makes your code worse**.

So, I best instead explain what's truly wrong with this code instead!

--

The underlying problem is that you've turned a boolean into a ternary state: It can be `true`, `false`, **OR** `null`, and this makes sense only in the SQL sense: That `null` is indicative of unknown, not applicable, or not yet set. In all 3 such cases, treating `null` as `false` is just plain wrong.

Whatever makes statusless be `null`? Fix that. Make it not be that. If it's a thing you get from another system, fix it in the other system (Example: If this is a nullable BOOLEAN db column, give it a non-null constraint and a `FALSE` default value), or if you can't fix it in the other system, fix it immediately once the data arrives at 'your side' of the code.

Once you've done all that, the possibility for `statusless` to be `null` goes away.

NB: Linting tools like sonar are a really bad idea unless you fully understand each and every warning it gives you. A linting tool tends to find medium to low-level problems with code, and can rarely detect high-level, more important issues with code, as is the case here.

If somehow you want to ignore this advice as you have determined that carrying on with a lying variable ('boolean', even 'Boolean', rather strongly suggests either 2 states, or perhaps 2 states + the ability to remain unset, but certainly not 'three states') is correct anyway, you can simply replace `statusless == null || statusless == false` with: `!Boolean.TRUE.equals(statusless)`. `Boolean.TRUE` reports `false` unless you pass a `true` value - so whether `statusless` is `false` or `null` - either way, `TRUE.equals(that)` will return `false`. Flip that `false` into `true` and voila.

You can't write `!statusless` because that will throw an NPE if `statusless` is null.

### But wait! Alternate interpretation!

Perhaps that Boolean really is supposed to represent the borderline acceptable notion of 'this value is either true, or false, or hasn't been set yet / does not apply to this situation', in which case the NPE is precisely what you want here: You can't determine whether to filter by validity status or not, and yet you must here, therefore this code cannot continue and the error lies in the caller having set up invalid state before calling this method. In that case, you really just want `return !statusless ? ...  : ...;`

Comment: "In that case, you really just want" in this case it is better to make the parameter `boolean`; then you're not hiding the fact that this method _will_ throw an NPE if passed a null value. If you make the parameter boolean, the unboxing occurs in the caller's code, not this code, which makes it clear whose responsibility it is to avoid.

Comment: Yes, if it's passed in as param, by all means make it lowercase.